# UWP PivotPanel Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I created a new blank windows universal app and dragged a PivotPanel on the empty page. When I take a look in the XAML-Editor it marks the PivotPanel line tells me the following:
Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)

Does anyone have a clue why this happens?

XAML-Code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <PivotPanel/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Using this for mobile developement

Comment: `PivotPanel` isn't typically used for general XAML UI composition. It is used to display the items in a Pivot control. Why you need this control?